# Disable the "open session" popup in chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, google-chrome

I have a problem that didn't exist before, now when my session expires, I have this popup that appears on my site!

[image]

It seems to be a chrome feature!

How can I programmatically disable it?

Also it does not work!

The problem doesn't appear locally but only from the production server!

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is an HTTP Basic Authentication and has nothing to do with chrome specifically.

Comment: @moritzg thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use ASP.NET Core and I solved my problem by changing an option in IIS:

On the `"Authentication"` page, select `"Basic Authentication"` and disabling it!

[More info](https://www.omnisecu.com/security/internet-information-services-iis-7-security/how-configure-basic-authentication-in-iis-7.php)

Answer (score 1):

This is HTTP Basic Authentication and has nothing to do with Chrome specifically.